# RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasSgemm( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, &beta, c, ldc)`

Tags: python, jupyter, sentiment-analysis, topic-modeling, cuda-gdb

I'm trying to extract feathers from BertTopic model and I'm using jupyter notebook.
The first feature is sentiment analysis and it's done by following code:
df-DataFrame,
df["title_selftext"] - this data frame column contain a text (str)

```
  def get_sentiment(model, tokenizer, data):
     inputs = tokenizer(data, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")
     outputs = model(**inputs.to(device))
     return torch.nn.functional.softmax(outputs.logits.detach())

 res = []
 for txt in tqdm(batches(df["title_selftext"],20), total=len(df)//32):
    **res.append(get_sentiment(model,tokenizer, list(txt)))**
```

when im trying to append the get_sentiment output i for this error:
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasSgemm( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, b, ldb, &beta, c, ldc)`

please help me to solve this error
Thank you